# I need to find rank in mysql in the following fashion

Tags: mysql

If there are duplicates, the highest order of duplicate to be taken.
eg:

```
Value - Rank
-----------
10    - 1
20    - 3
20    - 3
30    - 5
30    - 5
40    - 6
50    - 7
```

20 comes in 2nd and 3rd position, hence the rank is 3 ;  30 comes in 4th and 5th position, hence the rank is 5 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t3.value, maxrank
from your_table t3
join
(
    select t1.value, max(t2.rank) as maxrank
    from your_table t1
    join
    (
        select value, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
        from your_table
        cross join (select @rank := 0) r
        order by value
    ) t2 on t1.value = t2.value
    group by t1.value
) t4 on t3.value = t4.value
```

Comment: Don't know how much to thank you. Your are a genius.